# reading input from text file into array of structures in c

Tags: c, arrays, structure, file-processing

My structure definition is,

```
typedef struct {
    int taxid;
    int geneid;
    char goid[20];
    char evidence[4];
    char qualifier[20];
    char goterm[50];
    char pubmed;
    char category[20];    
} gene2go;
```

I have tab-seperated text file called `"gene2go.txt".

Each line of this file contains `taxID`, `geneID`, `goID`, `evidence`, `qualifier`, `goterm`, `pubmed` and `category` information.

Each line of the file will be kept in a structure.

When the program is run, it will first read the content of the input file into an array of type gene2go, I used a function called `readInfo`.

The program will also take the following input arguments from the command line,

input type ( 1 for `taxid`, 2 for `geneid`, 3 for `goid` ) and search term

There is a function called `listData` to write the list of lines in the file “gene2go.txt” that match the input type and search term, to the file “output.txt”.

Here is a part of my text file `"gene2go.txt"`,

```
3702    814629  GO:0003676  IEA -   nucleic acid binding    -   Function
3702    814629  GO:0005575  ND  -   cellular_component  -   Component
3702    814629  GO:0005634  ISM -   nucleus -   Component
3702    814629  GO:0008150  ND  -   biological_process  -   Process
3702    814629  GO:0008270  IEA -   zinc ion binding    -   Function
3702    814630  GO:0005634  ISM -   nucleus -   Component
3702    814636  GO:0008150  ND  -   biological_process  -   Process
3702    814637  GO:0003674  ND  -   molecular_function  -   Function
6239    177883  GO:0008150  ND  -   biological_process  -   Process
6239    177884  GO:0005575  ND  -   cellular_component  -   Component
6239    177884  GO:0008150  ND  -   biological_process  -   Process
6239    177886  GO:0004364  IDA -   glutathione transferase activity    12757851    Function
6239    177886  GO:0005575  ND  -   cellular_component  -   Component
7955    555450  GO:0005634  IEA -   nucleus -   Component
7955    555450  GO:0006355  IEA -   regulation of transcription, DNA-dependent  -   Process
```

I have written the code below named ceng301.c and compiled it using the command line

`gcc ceng301.c -o ceng301`

, but when I write

`ceng301 1 3702`

in the command line, I get nothing, but a blinking underscore :( instead of

```
3702    814629  GO:0003676  IEA -   nucleic acid binding    -   Function
3702    814629  GO:0005575  ND  -   cellular_component  -   Component
3702    814629  GO:0005634  ISM -   nucleus -   Component
3702    814629  GO:0008150  ND  -   biological_process  -   Process
3702    814629  GO:0008270  IEA -   zinc ion binding    -   Function
3702    814630  GO:0005634  ISM -   nucleus -   Component
3702    814636  GO:0008150  ND  -   biological_process  -   Process
3702    814637  GO:0003674  ND  -   molecular_function  -   Function
```

saved in `output.txt`

Here is the code,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* structure definition */
typedef struct {
    int taxid;
    int geneid;
    char goid[20];
    char evidence[4];
    char qualifier[20];
    char goterm[50];
    char *pubmed;
    char category[20];
} gene2go;

/* function prototypes */
int readInfo( gene2go input[] );
void listData( char *inType, char *searchItem, gene2go input[], int i );

int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
   gene2go input[200];
   int i;

   i = readInfo( input );
   listData( argv[1], argv[2], input, i );

   return 0;
}

/* read the input file*/
int readInfo( gene2go input[] ) {
   FILE *fin;
   char *inputName = "gene2go.txt";
   int i = 0;

   fin = fopen( inputName, "r" );

   if( fin == NULL ) {
      printf( "File cannot be opened\n" );
   } /* end if */
   else {
      while( !feof( fin ) ) {
        fscanf( fin, "%[^\t]", &input[i].taxid,
                               &input[i].geneid,
                               &input[i].goid,
                               &input[i].evidence,
                               &input[i].qualifier,
                               &input[i].goterm,
                               &input[i].pubmed,
                               &input[i].category );
        i++;
     } /* end while */

     fclose( fin );
  } /* end else */

  return i;
} /* end function readInfo */

void listData( char *inType, char* searchItem, gene2go input[], int i ) {
   FILE *fout;
   char *outputName = "output.txt";
   int j;
   int inputType = atoi( inType );

   fout = fopen( outputName, "w" );

   switch( inputType ) {
      case 1:
          for( j = 0; j < i; j++ ) {
               if( input[j].taxid == atoi( searchItem ) ) {
                   fprintf( fout, "%d\t%d\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\n", input[i].taxid,
                                                                      input[i].geneid,
                                                                      input[i].goid,
                                                                      input[i].evidence,
                                                                      input[i].qualifier,
                                                                      input[i].goterm,
                                                                      input[i].pubmed,
                                                                      input[i].category );
               } /* end if */
          } /* end for */
          break;
     case 2:
          for( j = 0; j < i; j++ ) {
              if( input[j].geneid == atoi( searchItem ) ) {
                  fprintf( fout, "%d\t%d\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\n", input[i].taxid,
                                                                     input[i].geneid,
                                                                     input[i].goid,
                                                                     input[i].evidence,
                                                                     input[i].qualifier,
                                                                     input[i].goterm,
                                                                     input[i].pubmed,
                                                                     input[i].category );
              } /* end if */
          } /* end for */
          break;
     case 3:
          for( j = 0; j < i; j++ ) {
              if( input[j].goid == searchItem ) {
                  fprintf( fout, "%d\t%d\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\n", input[i].taxid,
                                                                     input[i].geneid,
                                                                     input[i].goid,
                                                                     input[i].evidence,
                                                                     input[i].qualifier,
                                                                     input[i].goterm,
                                                                     input[i].pubmed,
                                                                     input[i].category );
              } /* end if */
          } /* end for */
          break;
 } /* end switch */

 fclose( fout );
} /* end function listData */
```

What should I do?

Comment: [fscanf](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/functions/scanf.html) and [fgets](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/functions/fgets.html) seem like reasonable functions to utilize for addressing this problem, and the usage of both is well documented. it seems you already have an idea on how to start solving this. What more are you looking for?

Comment: You need to explain how to translate strings to `int` for the `pubmed` and `category` fields.

Comment: Irrespective to your question ('learn... fscanf'), why you've decided to use C for such task? It's not the best-for-all language for at least 20 years.

Comment: In your struct, shouldn't `pubmed` be a `char *`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
char mystring[100];
FILE *p = fopen ("gene2go.txt" , "r");
if (p == NULL) perror ("Error opening file");
   else {
     if ( fgets (mystring , 100 , pFile) != NULL )
       puts (mystring);
      pch = strtok (mystring, "\t");
      while (pch != NULL)
      {
          //handle each token here and insert into struct
          pch = strtok (NULL, "\t");
      }
     fclose (pFile);
   }
   return 0;
```

Refer to **[strtok](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strtok/)**, **[fgets](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fgets/)**

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will refer to strtok and fgets as you suggest, and hopefully I will write the complete code for this problem.